# kickstarting childbirth by rich investors

Tags: society, economy

Elves....

The cliche' of elves living a long life thus being very underachieving on the fertility side.

I was thinking of the implication, pregnancy and child not being something that paesants do to work the land or modern people do for the sake of romanticism.
Instead in this setting people, elven people are born through kickstarters.  Investors sending money to top notch breeders to afford the best food and instruction possible.
The child will be born like smelted iron ready to be forged into a tool. The child will work his first 150 years of life to payback the investors with interests.

Altough I have an accountant degree, I'm not an econosmit, thus I need help with the implications of this concepts.

Details:

Kickstarted elves surpass adult humans masterful artists in their painting skills at the age of 2 years old and are excellent singers. By the age of 12 they have top notch skills in military strategy and are skilled enough to perfrom an open heart surgery.

By the age of 20 elves are so smart they can litreally read minds from body language and use echolocation like bats without needing special organs for it.

By age 30 elves are required to be fluent  without an accent in at least 20 different languages and knowing the basics of at least other 30 languages.

You ever hear of those children prodigy being able to defeat actual chess masters? yeah kickstard elves a different breed, they are more powerful than that.

**Question**

What kind of policies would best protect the investors? Obviously Billions are being spent for every child, they better not be gambled money.

Comment: What is your worldbuilding problem?

Comment: This looks like an open ended, idea generation/branistorming question that will result in many valid answers. Such questions aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: @sphennings I can count a lot of similar #economy questions that have been considered a good fit for the site

Comment: @RPGlife It's not asking about the economy that's the issue. It's the open ended, make up a list of problems and propose solutions to each, nature of the question that's the problem.

Comment: ''Question:

What kind of policies would best protect the investors? Obviously Billions are being spent for every child, they better not be gambled money.'' @sphennings

Comment: doesn't look like a list of problems each with a different question to me, I didn't even list a single problem actually... not one

Comment: That's a broad and open ended question that is likely to result in many equally valid answers. Brainstorming questions aren't a good fit for this site. To quote from the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question."

Comment: @sphennings how can it be more specific than literally just asking for investment policies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133506/discussion-between-sphennings-and-rpg-life).

Comment: Quick question: what kind of echolocation is that? To have basic echolocation on air like how humans can you need at least something that makes sound, a pair of ears and the ability to process sound, but if you want very precise echolocation, especially with a longer range, in addition to a brain with well developed regions to interpret everything, you need very good hearing, preferably movable large ears (assuming you don't want a leaf nose) and the ability to produce loud sounds several times a second. "being extremely smart" isn't enough to cut it, otherwise we'd be able to rival most bats.

Comment: Also if you want policies to protect the investors, some more info about the world in which said investors live in would be ideal. Are there any laws regulating the civil rights of elves? Any problems with forcing an elf to undergo a life they don't want to and be forced to serve you to pay it back? Any risks associated with the breeder not delivering the elf? Is the business completely legal and properly legislated? What are the main risks to your investors for said policies to be needed in the first place?

Comment: If you can flush out the world in which this business happens a little more, some your main problems and even ways in which they can be solved might become a lot clearer, and if they don't, we'll be here, this time with a concept that's a little more centered in terms of what you need, what limitations are present and what specifics are still causing you trouble.

Comment: This rather presupposes that "top-notch breeders" are even a thing that can plausibly exist, and that even if they _did_ exist they're not already part of a stupendously rich and powerful hereditary aristocracy that would be uninterested in anything that any would be investors could possibly offer them.

Comment: This reads like it is a horrible match for the kick starter model. What would contributors get in return? This has by far a better match with bonds.

Comment: Lets also pause to consider the potential downsides to raising a super ultra genius omnidisciplinary artist and scientist, and then telling them that the fruits of their labor for the next 150 years are, uh, not theirs. And there are a bunch of ancient billionaires who'll be grumpy if their prodigy doesn't make bank. I can't see this ending well for one or both parties.

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based. This question has a lot of problems. Without providing *all* of the existing legal structure and law, there's no plausible way anyone can develop policies to protect the investors. Without providing *all* of the details concerning the economy, we can't determine how the investors may be impacted. To be honest, you've created godlike characters (kickstarted elves) that require an equal-and-opposite force to balance their power in your world. Failure to protect the investors sounds like a good solution to me.

Comment: Historically, the set of policies which protected investors are called [slavery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery) and [serfdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom). Note that mere [indentured servitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentured_servitude) doesn't work, because an unborn child cannot sign a contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no way to protect investors, but likely there is no interest in kickstarting as elves as you have described them are likely to own and control everything and not be motivated by money.**

I do not believe there is a "long term" solution, even in human terms and certainly not in elven terms.

The only possible short term solution is that world wide, elves are viewed as property not beings. They have no rights and can own nothing. Additionally, society must come with a baked in kill switch to terminate all elves on demand in the event that they are not abiding by their "contracts".

Anything less and elves will simple control everything there is to control and money will be meaningless to them. As a result, even "billions" will not motivate a "breeder" (who is almost certainly a multi-billionaire already) to sell their children into slavery.

Even then, elves being much smarter than people they are likely able to figure out a way. A single nation recognizing them with rights would eventually result in their total control of the planet. An elf CFO/financial advisor is sure to be able to purchase property through obfuscated company accounting and again you end up with elves controlling everything.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't use the kickstarter model.

It is the wrong model to use. This model works best for supporting a project that will produce a product that all supporters want to use/own enjoy individually.  Products that are niche or have unknown support for existing publishers/manufacturer to create.

#### issue bonds.

Use the bog standard way to get large amounts of money for a capital project, start issuing bonds.